# p5.js Canvas doesn't show anything when an input element is added through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, p5.js

For a bit of background, here's a super simplified version of the problem:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.innerHTML += "<input>";
}

function draw() {
    background(255, 0, 0);
}
```

What this *should* do is create a canvas (which it does), add an input to the body (which it does) and then make the canvas' background red (this is where nothing happens).

It seems that any code that is a part of p5 refuses to work (I've tried putting `background(255, 0, 0);` in setup as well, but that didn't work either). This includes things like `line` and `rect`.

What's going on here to cause the issue? Is there a way to fix this without having to use `appendChild` (which I have not tried as, although it might be the proper way to add elements, this project isn't huge and using `innerHTML +=` is way more convenient)?

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: In p5.js you need to use the DOM library. Please take a look at this youtube: [Interacting with the DOM using Sliders, Buttons and Text Inputs - p5.js Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=587qclhguQg)

Comment: I'd try it that way, but I know you don't need to use the DOM library. See one of my other projects: https://simplexshotz.github.io/piupiu.io and the code behind it: https://simplexshotz.github.io/piupiu.io/javascript.js

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you forgot to add the close tag. Try to change that line to:

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<input></input>";
```

And it should work.